# How do I deploy havana instead of grizzly?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I'm trying to install openstack havana dashboard but the dashboard is always grizzly... I use juju and maas to deploy the charms on a bootstrap node, set the `openstack-origin` to: `cloud:precise-havana` to all of the charms - keystone, nova-compute, nova-cloud-controller, cinder, glance, quantum, openstack-dashboard but no success.

Always - grizzly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Can you attach your config.yaml file? The one you use to configure the OpenStack charms.

Answer (score -1):

Have you followed Havana installation guide for steps other that `apt-get install openstack-dashborad` ?

you can find it here http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/install_dashboard.html

- check also the note for Ubuntu users

Remove the openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme package. This theme prevents translations, several menus as well as the network map from rendering correctly:

```
# apt-get remove --purge openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
```